# Very slow decode times with hevc with ffmpeg 4.1.4 on Ubuntu

Tags: video, vlc, ffmpeg, codecs

I'm getting ridiculously slow decode times for iPhone `hevc` .MOV files.

In VLC or ffplay, the video displays one frame every 10 seconds. Simply transcoding to h264 I get about 1.8 fps. I recall being able to play these videos fine with earlier versions of Ubuntu, but I cannot be sure.

Not sure if I'm missing a compile option in ffmpeg, if the hardware acceleration isn't working, or if I'm missing something else.

**My setup:**

- Ubuntu 19.10
- NVIDIA Quadro K1100M
- Proprietary NVidia drivers
- Stock ffmpeg from apt

ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1build2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-4ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1build2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared

Comment: Are you able to post the troublesome file somewhere? And what CPU for your machine?

Comment: CPU is a 4-core i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz

The files are rather large. iPhone 11 records in 4k.

Once I transcode these files to h264, I can play them fine on the same machine.

Comment: It would be interesting to see whats in your file. Could  you `ffmpeg -n -i inputfile.m4v` and paste the infos into your question?